# Why are some programs way faster than mine?

Tags: c, image, performance, loading

today I decided to load 75 million values into memory from a file and realized it was really slow. The file was a 5000 x 5000 picture which i know is unrealisticly huge but its good for testing. What my program does is load the picture into arrays so it can be edited. The thing is I made the picture with a program called paint.net and it loaded it up in lke 30 seconds no problem. So how do these image editing programs work so fast? I made my program in C so it should be just as fast as any other program out there right? I also made sure my loop for loading the image is really basic and doesnt have extra code slowing it down for no reason.

Comment: Impossible to say, without seeing your code. Optimisation is a rich topic.

Comment: You could post your code, or an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to see if you could get help with figuring out what might be wrong with your code.

Comment: (1) Use a profiler.  (2) Try reading the file into memory in one big chunk instead of many little reads.

Comment: The code is really simple its just array[location]=fgetc(fp);

Comment: appropriate to close, but i will just throw out there that without knowing anything about your code or the implementation of paint.net, i bet you are losing because they do memory mapped io and you do not

Comment: `fgetc()` is pretty slow when you're using it to read just one byte at a time. The best analogy I've seen is using `fgetc()` is like buying fish from the market one at a time, while using something like `fread()` is like buying fish by the freezerful (great if you need a lot of fish, annoying if you just need one). The programming language you use doesn't determine whether your program is fast or slow, but it's the techniques and algorithms that you use.

Comment: OP added the detail needed to make this question answerable (in a comment) so I've nominated it for reopening.

Answer (score 3):

Why not read the source of those other programs? Paint.NET isn't open source, but the GIMP, which is similarly good at editing images, [is](http://www.gimp.org/source/howtos/gimp-git-build.html).

Comment: Paint.NET source code is available here: http://code.google.com/p/openpdn/